# Transcribe single-row CSV of booleans to multi-row, multi-column HTML table

Tags: php, csv

I've got this ridiculous data set to deal with which is just one big, long string of ones and zeroes, which represents columns corresponding to the day of the week every 24 items.  This is what I am actually up against:
   OFF,OFF,OFF,OFF,OFF,OFF,OFF,OFF,OFF,OFF,OFF,OFF,OFF,OFF,OFF,OFF,OFF,OFF,OFF,OFF,OFF,OFF,OFF,OFF,OFF,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,OFF,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,OFF,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,OFF,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,OFF,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,OFF,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON

And to draw an example of this (again, just one big long string) comma separated value, with newlines added every 24th item to make it more clear:

```
(versus something I've formatted to make it clear)
(monday) 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
(tues) 0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
(wed) 0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
(thurs) 0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
(fri) 0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
(sat) 0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
(sun) 0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
```

I need to get this data set into an HTML table where things look more like what I've pasted to pastebin here:

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<th>
<th>Monday</th>
<th>Tuesday</th>
<th>Wednesday</th>
<th>Thursday</th>
<th>Friday</th>
<th>Saturday</th>
<th>Sunday</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="hourHeader">0:00</td>
<td id="1-0" class="highlightOn highlightOff">OFF</td>
<td id="2-0" class="highlightOn highlightOff">OFF</td>
<td id="3-0" class="highlightOn highlightOff">OFF</td>
<td id="4-0" class="highlightOn highlightOff">OFF</td>
<td id="5-0" class="highlightOn highlightOff">OFF</td>
<td id="6-0" class="highlightOn highlightOff">OFF</td>
<td id="7-0" class="highlightOn highlightOff">OFF</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="hourHeader">1:00</td>
<td id="1-1" class="highlightOn highlightOff">OFF</td>
<td id="2-1" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="3-1" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="4-1" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="5-1" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="6-1" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="7-1" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="hourHeader">2:00</td>
<td id="1-2" class="highlightOn highlightOff">OFF</td>
<td id="2-2" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="3-2" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="4-2" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="5-2" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="6-2" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="7-2" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="hourHeader">3:00</td>
<td id="1-3" class="highlightOn highlightOff">OFF</td>
<td id="2-3" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="3-3" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="4-3" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="5-3" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="6-3" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="7-3" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="hourHeader">4:00</td>
<td id="1-4" class="highlightOn highlightOff">OFF</td>
<td id="2-4" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="3-4" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="4-4" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="5-4" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="6-4" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="7-4" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="hourHeader">5:00</td>
<td id="1-5" class="highlightOn highlightOff">OFF</td>
<td id="2-5" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="3-5" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="4-5" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="5-5" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="6-5" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="7-5" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="hourHeader">6:00</td>
<td id="1-6" class="highlightOn highlightOff">OFF</td>
<td id="2-6" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="3-6" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="4-6" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="5-6" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="6-6" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="7-6" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="hourHeader">7:00</td>
<td id="1-7" class="highlightOn highlightOff">OFF</td>
<td id="2-7" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="3-7" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="4-7" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="5-7" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="6-7" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="7-7" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="hourHeader">8:00</td>
<td id="1-8" class="highlightOn highlightOff">OFF</td>
<td id="2-8" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="3-8" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="4-8" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="5-8" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="6-8" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="7-8" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="hourHeader">9:00</td>
<td id="1-9" class="highlightOn highlightOff">OFF</td>
<td id="2-9" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="3-9" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="4-9" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="5-9" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="6-9" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="7-9" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="hourHeader">10:00</td>
<td id="1-10" class="highlightOn highlightOff">OFF</td>
<td id="2-10" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="3-10" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="4-10" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="5-10" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="6-10" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="7-10" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="hourHeader">11:00</td>
<td id="1-11" class="highlightOn highlightOff">OFF</td>
<td id="2-11" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="3-11" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="4-11" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="5-11" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="6-11" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="7-11" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="hourHeader">12:00</td>
<td id="1-12" class="highlightOn highlightOff">OFF</td>
<td id="2-12" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="3-12" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="4-12" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="5-12" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="6-12" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="7-12" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="hourHeader">13:00</td>
<td id="1-13" class="highlightOn highlightOff">OFF</td>
<td id="2-13" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="3-13" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="4-13" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="5-13" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="6-13" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="7-13" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="hourHeader">14:00</td>
<td id="1-14" class="highlightOn highlightOff">OFF</td>
<td id="2-14" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="3-14" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="4-14" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="5-14" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="6-14" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="7-14" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="hourHeader">15:00</td>
<td id="1-15" class="highlightOn highlightOff">OFF</td>
<td id="2-15" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="3-15" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="4-15" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="5-15" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="6-15" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="7-15" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="hourHeader">16:00</td>
<td id="1-16" class="highlightOn highlightOff">OFF</td>
<td id="2-16" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="3-16" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="4-16" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="5-16" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="6-16" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="7-16" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="hourHeader">17:00</td>
<td id="1-17" class="highlightOn highlightOff">OFF</td>
<td id="2-17" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="3-17" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="4-17" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="5-17" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="6-17" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="7-17" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="hourHeader">18:00</td>
<td id="1-18" class="highlightOn highlightOff">OFF</td>
<td id="2-18" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="3-18" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="4-18" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="5-18" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="6-18" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="7-18" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="hourHeader">19:00</td>
<td id="1-19" class="highlightOn highlightOff">OFF</td>
<td id="2-19" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="3-19" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="4-19" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="5-19" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="6-19" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="7-19" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="hourHeader">20:00</td>
<td id="1-20" class="highlightOn highlightOff">OFF</td>
<td id="2-20" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="3-20" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="4-20" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="5-20" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="6-20" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="7-20" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="hourHeader">21:00</td>
<td id="1-21" class="highlightOn highlightOff">OFF</td>
<td id="2-21" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="3-21" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="4-21" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="5-21" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="6-21" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="7-21" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="hourHeader">22:00</td>
<td id="1-22" class="highlightOn highlightOff">OFF</td>
<td id="2-22" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="3-22" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="4-22" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="5-22" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="6-22" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="7-22" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="hourHeader">23:00</td>
<td id="1-23" class="highlightOn highlightOff">OFF</td>
<td id="2-23" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="3-23" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="4-23" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="5-23" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="6-23" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
<td id="7-23" class="highlightOn">ON</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

And represented in preformatted text here:

```
hour|m|t|w|t|f|s|s
0:00|0|0|0|0|0|0|0
1:00|0|1|1|1|1|1|1
2:00|0|1|1|1|1|1|1
3:00|0|1|1|1|1|1|1
4:00|0|1|1|1|1|1|1
5:00|0|1|1|1|1|1|1
6:00|0|1|1|1|1|1|1
7:00|0|1|1|1|1|1|1
8:00|0|1|1|1|1|1|1
9:00|0|1|1|1|1|1|1
10:00|0|1|1|1|1|1|1
11:00|0|1|1|1|1|1|1
12:00|0|1|1|1|1|1|1
13:00|0|1|1|1|1|1|1
14:00|0|1|1|1|1|1|1
15:00|0|1|1|1|1|1|1
16:00|0|1|1|1|1|1|1
17:00|0|1|1|1|1|1|1
18:00|0|1|1|1|1|1|1
19:00|0|1|1|1|1|1|1
20:00|0|1|1|1|1|1|1
21:00|0|1|1|1|1|1|1
22:00|0|1|1|1|1|1|1
23:00|0|1|1|1|1|1|1
```

I've tried iterating over this data in a bunch of different ways, none of which have done the trick so far. Does anyone have any suggestions while I run my codemonkey head against this tree some more, hopefully to have a coconut drop? They've gone and chopped off my hands, so I am unable to just go climb the source of this nutty tree to get a proper CSV with real columns and rows, which is the solution I had in mind before I learned it wasn't an option for one peter's principle reason or another. A glass of young coconut water to anyone who I may thank in advance for a suggestion. It's got electrolytes!

**EDIT: Here's the answer:**

```
$days_hours = array_chunk($input, 24);

array_unshift($days_hours, NULL); // reindexes
unset($days_hours[0]); // removes dummy "0" index

$hours_days = call_user_func_array('array_map', array(NULL)+$days_hours);

foreach($hours_days as $hourKey => $hour) {    

    echo '<tr><td id="hourHeader">' . $hourKey . ':00</td>';

    foreach($hour as $dayKey => $day) {

        $dayId = $dayKey + 1;
        $id = $dayId . '-' . $hourKey;

        if ($day === "1") {
            $text = "ON";
            $class = "highlightOn";
        } else {
            $text = "OFF";
            $class = "highlightOff";
        }

        if ($dayKey !== 6) {
            echo '<td class="' . $class . '" id="'. $id . '">' . $text . '</td>';
        } else {
            echo '<td class="' . $class . '" id="'. $id . '">' . $text . '</td></tr>';
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the non-working code that you have?

Comment: I would, but it doesn't do anything close to useful. Beyond that, the alpha monkey won't allow it (just asked, probably should have kept my mouth shut. It seems how stuff gets done around here. Peter's principle is in full effect). But to get the jist of my approach, I was trying to iterate over hours first, then days in a contained for loop, adding +25 for the next tuesday on hour 00:00, 25+24 for the wednesday after that, 25+24+24 for friday, so on, so forth... I'm puzzled over where to even start on the next row, really.

Comment: read it in with fgetcsv, then loop through the resultant array copying every block of 24 into a separate day. then loop through the days pulling out each hour.

Comment: To explain a bit further, I have taken the string and imploded it into an array to target items within that according to some offset rules. Really wish I could post code, though.

Comment: Please paste your code directly into the question, rather than posting to an outside service like pastebin.  The external code can go away at any time, and there is no version control over it like with SO questions.  Therefore, future readers will probably not be able to see the external code and thus this question will be useless or not make much sense. **StackOverflow is as much about future reference for others as it is about you getting your question answered today.**

Comment: Thanks for the newbie suggestion, Andy. I've fixed things up and will make sure to conform to that standard from here on in if I need to ask any more questions (And stackoverflow has been useful enough with pre-asked questions that I have been finding answers on it since 2010 and never felt the compulsion to ask a thing until now, awesome!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not very hard, I think?

```
$input = "OFF,OFF,OFF,OFF,OFF,OFF,OFF,OFF,OFF,OFF,OFF,OFF,OFF,OFF,OFF,OFF,OFF,OFF,OFF,OFF,OFF,OFF,OFF,OFF,OFF,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,OFF,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,OFF,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,OFF,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,OFF,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,OFF,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON,ON";


function on_off_to_bool($v) {
    static $map = array('OFF'=>false,'ON'=>true);
    return $map[strtoupper($v)];
}

$input_array = explode(',', $input);
$input_bools = array_map('on_off_to_bool', $input_array);

$days_hours = array_chunk($input_bools, 24);

// $days_hours is now an array of days of the week, 0-indexed,
// each containing an array of BOOLs by hour, 0-indexed.

// If you want 1-indexed days, do this:
array_unshift($days_hours, NULL); // reindexes
unset($days_hours[0]); // removes dummy "0" index

var_export($days_hours);
```

Generating your desired HTML from `$days_hours` should be trivial.

**UPDATE**

Actually it occurs to me that it is a little bit less than trivial because you want your table to be hour-oriented rather than day-oriented. No matter:

```
$hours_days = call_user_func_array('array_map', array(NULL)+$days_hours);
```

Now generate the HTML:

```
$headers = array('hour', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday');
?>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
<?php foreach($headers as $header):?>
        <th><?=$header?></th>
<?php endforeach?>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
<?php foreach($hours_days as $hour => $week):?>
     <tr>
        <th class="hourHeader"><?=$hour?>:00</th>
<?php   foreach($week as $dow => $value):
            $id = 'schedule-'.($dow+1).'-'.$hour;
            $class = ($value) ? 'highlightOn' : 'highlightOff';
            $text = ($value) ? "ON" : "OFF";
?>
        <td id="<?=$id?>" class="<?=$class?>"><?=$text?></td>
<?php   endforeach?>
     </tr>
<?php endforeach?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, I've got a solution similar to this along with the winning answer down the line now.

Comment: Your "winning answer" gives you an array of days-of-the-week, when I thought you wanted an array of hours?

Comment: Yes, your answer is the winrar. I'm out of gold nuggets and young coconut water, unfortunately, and I'm still too new here to upvote your much-helpful answer, so here's a big thanks instead :)

Comment: It's a Python idiom, where it's pronounced `zip(*array)`.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
$values = explode(',', $inputData);
$days = array_chunk($values, 24);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php

Semantically the same as @Madbreak's solution: You get an array which contains an array of hour values for each day.

Comment: lethal-guitar wins the glass of young coconut water and a chunk of internet gold! Glad to see a function built into PHP for once that doesn't make me want to burn the project written in the darn language onto a CD for installation on a nuclear missle to launch towards Zend headquarters. I'd link up an upvote for you, but it appears I'm too fresh here to do that.

Comment: Don't I feel dumb. That's awesome though, I've never used `array_chunk` before.

Comment: It turns out that Francis Avila's answer is the winrar. You were only halfway there. Just try and draw up an html table from arrays representing columns, I dare you (Left me messing around for hours). I know I did till I looked past all the horrible left-associative ternary operators and stuff in his answer to the juicy array_unshift($days_hours, NULL);
unset($days_hours[0]); $hours_days = call_user_func_array('array_map', array(NULL)+$days_hours); - this flips things around in per-hour arrays that can be directly iterated with nested foreach loops into typically laterally-drawn html tables :)

Comment: Well it's certainly possible using two nested for-loops, with the outer one going from 0..24 and the inner one from 0..7. In each inner iteration, you can then index like that: `$days[$j][$i]`. But I have to agree that the other solution feels much more natural and is easier to comprehend :)

Answer (score 1):

Start with, uh, how about:

```
$bits = explode(',', $bigLongString);
$days = array();
$hours = 24;

for($day=0; $day < 7; $day++){
    for($i=0; $i<$hours; $i++){
        $days[$day][] = $bits[$i + $hours * $day];
    }
}
```

That'd get you to something like:

```
array (
    // day 0
    0 => array(
        OFF,OFF,OFF, ... OFF   // 24 entries
    )
    // ... to index (day) 6
)
```

That should be enough to get you started I think?  I should mention that yeah, this has not been tested.

Comment: Thanks kindly for the suggestion. Is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Quick, dirty and untested but this should give an array of hours. Each entry will contain an array of weekdays (Mon -0, Tue - 1, e.t.c.) with their value.

```
$values = str_getcsv($csvString);
$hourMap = array();

$hour = 0;
$weekday = 0;
foreach($values as $value){
    if(!array_key_exists($hour,$hourMap)){
        $hourMap[$hour] = array();
    }
    $hourMap[$hour][$weekday] = $value;
    $hour = ($hour + 1)%24;
    if($hour == 0){
        $weekday = ($weekday + 1)%7;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks kindly for the suggestion. Is appreciated.